# Adding a growth transition to a rect

Tags: css, svg, bar-chart, rect

I'm trying to do some nice transition either dynamically through d3 or using CSS for rects but I am having little lucky finding a good example of how to do so.

The idea is that I want to grow my bar chart from bottom to top when its being rendered.

The chart is rendered using Vega, which I don't believe has built in transitions yet, so I need other options to do outside of the library.

I attempted to use CSS animate, but it has some weird rendering issues and also goes top to bottom rather then bottom to top

```
rect {
  animation: bar-fill 2s linear;
}

@keyframes bar-fill {
  0% { height: 0; }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zg2hnr2x/3/

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS approach will currently only work in Chrome.  `height` is not officially an attribute that can be animated with CSS (yet).

The reason that it grows from top to bottom is because the coordinate origin of SVGs is at the top-left, and so the `x`,`y` coordinate of a `<rect>` is also at the top left.  The bottom right of a rect is at `x+width`,`y+height`.

If you need a cross-browser way to animate SVG elements then may want to look into one of the many JS SVG Animation libraries that are available.